# Core Data Error: SQLite error code:1, 'cannot rollback - no transaction is active'

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Im getting this error in the console and after that there are only errors. The error appears in a random order. Some of the db changes and saves work until the error appear.

I tried to clean project, remove the app from phone and restart the phone. 
In simulator it works fine! I tried with a 3GS and it works fine,i just tried with a 4/4S and the same problem occurs!

Log:

```
CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
CoreData: annotation: getting max pk for entityID = 2
CoreData: annotation: updating max pk for entityID = 2 with old = 19 and new = 20
CoreData: sql: ROLLBACK
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.2242s for 1 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZJIDSTR, t0.ZLASTUPDATED, t0.ZPHOTOHASH, t0.ZWAITINGFORFETCH, t0.ZVCARDAVATARREL, t0.ZVCARDTEMPREL FROM ZXMPPVCARDCOREDATASTORAGEOBJECT t0 WHERE  t0.ZJIDSTR = ?  LIMIT 1
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0128s
CoreData: details: SQLite bind[11] = "oIBWsotpJjWH8MAgnj9H56UtxXk="
CoreData: sql: COMMIT
CoreData: annotation: Disconnecting from sqlite database due to an error.
CoreData: error: (1) I/O error for database at /var/mobile/Applications/EB102CE9-77A8-4360-8D4E-3EEB55D21E8F/Library/ClientDB/StoreContent/persistentStore.  SQLite error code:1, 'cannot rollback - no transaction is active'

CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/var/mobile/Applications/EB102CE9-77A8-4360-8D4E-3EEB55D21E8F/Library/ClientDB/StoreContent/persistentStore"
CoreData: error: (14) unable to open database file
```

The only things I'm doing is:
Add new entities, edit attributes. Save.
I'm using the UIManagedDocument.

And from now on I will only get the same error, that it is impossible to open the database.
I have no fopen in my code. So it could not be a filedescriptor miss use.

Comment: Please provide your core data calls that are related to the error

Comment: They are quite random. Normally it happens on a save to disk.

Comment: Not enough information. Did you call `rollback` in your code?

Comment: I think i might be close to the solution, i disabled localytics and now it works. The problem might be not enough file descriptors. Localytics lib might be bugged.